# Pushing to remote Git repository from local project folder

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

This is what I need to do.

I have a project folder in my local drive. And my local Git repository is somewhere else on the local drive. I need to push the project folder to a remote Git repository. Without creating a new repository in my project folder or moving the project folder to local Git repository.

I have TortoiseGit. And Eclipse with the Git plugin.

I mostly use Subversion (SVN). I know the above is possible in SVN, but is it possible with Git?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your project folder, you can use `GIT_DIR` to specify where your Git repository is:

```
 cd /project/folder
 GIT_DIR=/path/to/repo/.git git add .
 GIT_DIR=/path/to/repo/.git git commit -m "my commit message"
```

That means you are considering your project folder as a working directory for a Git repository which is located elsewhere.